# Error in double pointer deletion

Tags: pointers

I am having a problem while working with double pointers. I want to assign the string to Dinfo.phrase. Code runs fine till the statement delete[] newp. When this statement is executed then following error appears.

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ...exe
this may be due to corruption of heap, which indicates a bug in teststring.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

here is the code

```
struct dlgbox {
    char *temp;  };

void test(char **newp){
    dlgbox Dinfo;
    char *test="test";
    Dinfo.temp= NULL;
    Dinfo.temp=test;
    *newp = Dinfo.temp;
    printf("%s \n",*newp);}

int main(){
    char *newp=NULL;
    test(&newp);
    printf("main se ==%s ",newp);
    printf("\nstrlen %d ",strlen(newp));
    delete[] newp;
    _getch();
    return 0;}
```

Please help me!! is this problem due to pointer deletion?? how can a pointer be deleted in my particular case??

Comment: I want to assign the string to Dinfo.temp and finally to newp*

Comment: You should never need to add a comment in (direct) response to your own questions or answers. If you have more information to give, please use the edit link (at the bottom of your question) to add it into your question. Also, please add a language tag at the same time (I'm almost certain it's C++, but this site is for programmers for all kinds of languages, so tags help to make sure your question is visible to the right people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two mistakes. First, you use local variable to initialize the pointer with. That's wrong because after `test` is finished the `Dinfo`s address may contain everything as the object is marked as out of use. Second, you call `delete[]`. That's wrong because no `new` was called as it should(instead of using local variable) be. Also even if you rewrite your code with `new`, do not call `delete[]`, just `delete`.

Plase, read [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) about memory usage carefully.